# Python If Statement within JSON

Tags: python, json

I have python script with JSON input variable.

I would need to include tags part to the input JSON only when myTag is defined.

Is there any way how to do this in python?

Thanks a lot.

```
data = {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "event.get",
        "params": {
            "output": [
                "eventid",
                "name"
            ],
            if myTag not None:
               "tags": [
                   {
                       "tag": myTag,
                       "value": myValue
                   }
               ],
            "sortorder": "DESC",
        },
        "id": 1
    }
```

Comment: You can simply ass the substructure in an other statement protected by an `if`.

Comment: yes, create the python `dict` in two parts; first part with everything that is there unconditionally, then second part insert the conditional item  `tags` list. Then use `json.dumps(data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize the section which doesn't have conditional checks first and later assign conditional parts separately. Also in python, the code you have written is a dictionary creation rather than a JSON creation

```
data = {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "event.get",
        "params": {
            "output": [
                "eventid",
                "name"
            ],

            "sortorder": "DESC",
        },
        "id": 1
    }
```

Conditional parts can be initialised as below.

```
if myTag not None:
   data["params"]["tags"]= [{"tag": myTag, "value": myValue}]
```